# macbook pro randomly going to sleep

Tags: macos, sleep-wake

I have a early 2011 macbook pro with mountain lion 10.8.2 installed in it, I have sleepawake installed and disabled energy saving option all set to forever.

[image: energy perferences]

the problem is the system is still going to sleep randomly without any sort of common behaviour , I reinstalled ML and still no luck, this problem was there before but it happened maybe once in several days, now it is much more frequent and can be triggered even by spacebar press or nothing at all, what can be reason for this.

here are list of kexts in my system

```
Index Refs Address            Size       Wired      Name (Version) <Linked Against>
1   83 0xffffff7f80756000 0x686c     0x686c     com.apple.kpi.bsd (12.2.0)
2    6 0xffffff7f80741000 0x46c      0x46c      com.apple.kpi.dsep (12.2.0)
3  110 0xffffff7f80760000 0x1b7ec    0x1b7ec    com.apple.kpi.iokit (12.2.0)
4  115 0xffffff7f8074c000 0x99f8     0x99f8     com.apple.kpi.libkern (12.2.0)
5  103 0xffffff7f80742000 0x88c      0x88c      com.apple.kpi.mach (12.2.0)
6   39 0xffffff7f80743000 0x500c     0x500c     com.apple.kpi.private (12.2.0)
7   58 0xffffff7f80749000 0x23cc     0x23cc     com.apple.kpi.unsupported (12.2.0)
8    0 0xffffff7f814c5000 0x41000    0x41000    com.apple.kec.corecrypto (1.0) <7 6 5 4 3 1>
9   24 0xffffff7f808fa000 0x9000     0x9000     com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily (1.4) <7 6 4 3>
10   32 0xffffff7f8077c000 0x25000    0x25000    com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily (2.7.2) <7 6 5 4 3>
11    2 0xffffff7f81df4000 0x57000    0x57000    com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform (1.6) <10 9 7 6 5 4 3 1>
12   16 0xffffff7f807a5000 0x57000    0x57000    com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily (5.4.0) <10 7 5 4 3 1>
13    6 0xffffff7f80931000 0x2b000    0x2b000    com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily (3.5.1) <5 4 3 1>
14   11 0xffffff7f80884000 0x25000    0x25000    com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily (1.8) <7 6 5 4 3 1>
15    1 0xffffff7f80962000 0x16000    0x16000    com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice (3.5.1) <14 13 5 4 3 1>
16    2 0xffffff7f8097b000 0x7000     0x7000     com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite (5.2.5) <12 4 3 1>
17    1 0xffffff7f80982000 0x11000    0x11000    com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass (3.5.0) <14 13 12 5 4 3 1>
18    0 0xffffff7f80996000 0x18000    0x18000    com.rim.driver.BlackBerryUSBDriverInt (0.0.74) <17 16 15 13 12 5 4 3 1>
19    1 0xffffff7f80b25000 0xe000     0xe000     com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore (28.21) <7 6 5 4 3 1>
20    0 0xffffff7f80e68000 0x19000    0x19000    com.apple.driver.DiskImages (344) <14 7 6 5 4 3 1>
21    0 0xffffff7f81b15000 0x29000    0x29000    com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement (196.0.0) <7 6 5 4 3 1>
22    0 0xffffff7f8075d000 0x3000     0x3000     com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet (7) <7 6 5 4 2 1>
23    2 0xffffff7f8091c000 0x4000     0x4000     com.apple.kext.AppleMatch (1.0.0d1) <4 1>
24    1 0xffffff7f80920000 0x11000    0x11000    com.apple.security.sandbox (220) <23 7 6 5 4 3 2 1>
25    0 0xffffff7f809b4000 0x6000     0x6000     com.apple.security.quarantine (2) <24 23 7 6 5 4 2 1>
26    0 0xffffff7f81e62000 0x8000     0x8000     com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall (4.0.39) <7 6 5 4 3 1>
27    0 0xffffff7f81b10000 0x3000     0x3000     com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient (196.0.0) <7 6 5 4 3 1>
28    0 0xffffff7f81dc9000 0x3000     0x3000     com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC (1.6) <4 3>
29    3 0xffffff7f80d3a000 0x4000     0x4000     com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily (1.1) <5 4 3>
30    0 0xffffff7f81e51000 0x7000     0x7000     com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC (1.6) <29 11 9 5 4 3>
31    0 0xffffff7f81961000 0x4000     0x4000     com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS (1.9) <7 4 3>
32    0 0xffffff7f81b4a000 0x3000     0x3000     com.apple.driver.AppleHPET (1.7) <9 7 5 4 3>
33    7 0xffffff7f80b33000 0x6d000    0x6d000    com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily (1.8.0) <19 7 6 5 4 3 2 1>
34    0 0xffffff7f81e5b000 0x4000     0x4000     com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons (1.6) <33 11 9 7 6 5 4 3 1>
35    0 0xffffff7f8198b000 0x8000     0x8000     com.apple.driver.AppleRTC (1.5) <9 5 4 3 1>
36    1 0xffffff7f81d9c000 0x5000     0x5000     com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime (1.6.1) <7 6 5 4 3>
37    0 0xffffff7f81967000 0x8000     0x8000     com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager (161.0.0) <29 9 5 4 3 1>
38    0 0xffffff7f81da1000 0x7000     0x7000     com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM (1.6.1) <36 7 6 5 4 3>
39    3 0xffffff7f81050000 0x16000    0x16000    com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily (2.2.1) <5 4 3 1>
40    0 0xffffff7f81dce000 0x19000    0x19000    com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort (2.4.1) <39 10 5 4 3 1>
41    6 0xffffff7f80ae3000 0x2b000    0x2b000    com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily (3.0) <7 6 5 4 3 1>
42    1 0xffffff7f80dd2000 0x7000     0x7000     com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController (1.0.2b1) <41 5 4 3 1>
43    0 0xffffff7f80dd9000 0x35000    0x35000    com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet (3.2.5b3) <42 41 10 9 5 4 3 1>
44    0 0xffffff7f80c30000 0x18000    0x18000    com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI (5.4.0) <12 10 7 5 4 3 1>
46    0 0xffffff7f81974000 0x10000    0x10000    com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC (1.2.2) <14 10 5 4 3 1>
47    2 0xffffff7f80a24000 0x73000    0x73000    com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily (4.5.5) <5 4 3 1>
48    0 0xffffff7f80ec3000 0x27000    0x27000    com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI (4.9.6) <47 10 7 6 5 4 3 1>
49    1 0xffffff7f81099000 0x65000    0x65000    com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family (500.15) <41 7 6 5 4 3 1>
50    0 0xffffff7f81105000 0x1f2000   0x1f2000   com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331 (602.15.22) <49 41 10 7 5 4 3 1>
51    4 0xffffff7f80c60000 0xae000    0xae000    com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily (2.1.1) <5 4 3 1>
52    0 0xffffff7f8189e000 0x15000    0x15000    com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI (1.6.0) <51 10 9 5 4 3 1>
53    1 0xffffff7f80b22000 0x3000     0x3000     com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient (5.2.5) <12 7 5 4 3 1>
54    0 0xffffff7f80c15000 0x15000    0x15000    com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub (5.2.5) <12 5 4 3 1>
55    0 0xffffff7f81076000 0x16000    0x16000    com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage (2.2.2) <39 14 6 5 4 3 1>
56    0 0xffffff7f81069000 0xd000     0xd000     com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI (2.5.0) <39 13 5 4 3 1>
57    0 0xffffff7f817fb000 0x3000     0x3000     com.apple.driver.XsanFilter (404) <14 5 4 3 1>
58    0 0xffffff7f80d43000 0x7000     0x7000     com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient (3.5.1) <14 13 5 4 3 1>
59    3 0xffffff7f80d4e000 0xe000     0xe000     com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily (1.7.1) <14 5 4 3 1>
60    2 0xffffff7f80d5f000 0xb000     0xb000     com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily (1.7.1) <59 14 5 4 3 1>
61    1 0xffffff7f80d6d000 0xa000     0xa000     com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily (1.7) <60 59 14 5 4 3 1>
62    0 0xffffff7f80d7a000 0x1a000    0x1a000    com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice (3.5.1) <61 60 59 14 13 5 4 3 1>
63    0 0xffffff7f81515000 0x9000     0x9000     com.apple.BootCache (34) <7 6 5 4 3 1>
64    0 0xffffff7f81d8d000 0x4000     0x4000     com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib (1.0.0d1) <6 4 3 2 1>
65    0 0xffffff7f81d93000 0x3000     0x3000     com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless (1.0.0d1) <7 6 4 3 2 1>
67    0 0xffffff7f80c0e000 0x7000     0x7000     com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub (5.2.5) <16 12 4 3 1>
68    4 0xffffff7f80bb3000 0x9000     0x9000     com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver (5.2.5) <33 12 5 4 3 1>
69    0 0xffffff7f81a41000 0x4000     0x4000     com.apple.driver.AppleIRController (320.15) <68 33 12 5 4 3>
70    0 0xffffff7f8182f000 0x4000     0x4000     com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard (235.4) <68 33 12 7 6 5 4 3 1>
72    0 0xffffff7f8183a000 0x13000    0x13000    com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch (235.7) <68 33 12 6 5 4 3 1>
73    0 0xffffff7f81890000 0x5000     0x5000     com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter (1.2.5) <51 10 4 3>
74    1 0xffffff7f818b7000 0x9000     0x9000     com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily (1.8.5) <51 10 9 5 4 3>
75    0 0xffffff7f818c0000 0x5000     0x5000     com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter (1.8.5) <74 51 10 9 5 4 3>
76    0 0xffffff7f81835000 0x3000     0x3000     com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons (235.4) <68 33 12 7 6 5 4 3 1>
77    4 0xffffff7f80903000 0xd000     0xd000     com.apple.driver.AppleSMC (3.1.4d2) <9 7 5 4 3>
78    0 0xffffff7f80912000 0x7000     0x7000     com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor (3.0.2d6) <77 5 4 3>
79   14 0xffffff7f80e11000 0x38000    0x38000    com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily (2.3.5) <10 7 5 4 3>
80    2 0xffffff7f81950000 0xe000     0xe000     com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController (1.0.10d0) <29 10 9 5 4 3>
81    0 0xffffff7f81a03000 0xc000     0xc000     com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl (1.0.33) <80 79 10 9 7 5 4 3 1>
82    7 0xffffff7f80e54000 0x12000    0x12000    com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport (2.3.5) <79 10 7 5 4 3>
83    1 0xffffff7f81d6e000 0x5000     0x5000     com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert (1.0.4) <82 79 10 5 4 3>
84    0 0xffffff7f81dc1000 0x5000     0x5000     com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight (170.2.3) <83 82 79 10 5 4 3>
85    1 0xffffff7f81d5a000 0x3000     0x3000     com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl (3.2.11) <82 79 10 9 7 5 4 3 1>
87    5 0xffffff7f80d98000 0xa000     0xa000     com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily (5.2.0d16) <9 7 6 5 4 3>
88    0 0xffffff7f80da2000 0x3000     0x3000     com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC (1.0.0) <87 10 6 4 3>
89    1 0xffffff7f80da7000 0x12000    0x12000    com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy (1.0.0) <87 9 7 6 5 4 3>
90    0 0xffffff7f80dbb000 0x10000    0x10000    com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin (1.0.0) <89 87 77 10 9 7 6 5 4 3>
91    0 0xffffff7f81945000 0x5000     0x5000     com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU (2.0.2d0) <79 77 5 4 3>
92    0 0xffffff7f8194d000 0x3000     0x3000     com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI (1.0.10d0) <10 5 4 3>
93    0 0xffffff7f81a48000 0x2e000    0x2e000    com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB (8.0.0) <79 10 9 7 6 5 4 3 1>
94    0 0xffffff7f81b8e000 0x15000    0x15000    com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver (2.3.1f2) <80 9 5 4 3 1>
95    1 0xffffff7f80f35000 0x27000    0x27000    com.apple.iokit.AppleBluetoothHCIControllerUSBTransport (4.0.9f33) <12 10 9 7 5 4 3 1>
96    0 0xffffff7f80f5c000 0x10000    0x10000    com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHCIControllerUSBTransport (4.0.9f33) <95 12 10 9 7 5 4 3>
98    0 0xffffff7f81a88000 0x62000    0x62000    com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics (8.0.0) <82 79 10 7 5 4 3 1>
99    0 0xffffff7f81a39000 0x3000     0x3000     com.apple.driver.AppleLPC (1.6.0) <87 10 5 4 3>
100    0 0xffffff7f81d5d000 0xc000     0xc000     com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl (3.2.11) <85 82 79 10 9 7 5 4 3 1>
101    0 0xffffff7f813e8000 0x5000     0x5000     com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X (7.0.0) <77 7 4 3 1>
102    0 0xffffff7f80f6f000 0xa1000    0xa1000    com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily (4.0.9f33) <12 7 5 4 3 1>
103    0 0xffffff7f80d26000 0x12000    0x12000    com.apple.iokit.IOSurface (86.0.3) <7 5 4 3 1>
104    0 0xffffff7f80b15000 0x7000     0x7000     com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet (1.0.0d1) <41 6 5 4 3 1>
105    2 0xffffff7f81b7f000 0xc000     0xc000     com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily (2.3.1f2) <5 4 3 1>
106    1 0xffffff7f81bb5000 0x16000    0x16000    com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController (2.3.1f2) <105 79 10 6 5 4 3 1>
107    0 0xffffff7f81858000 0x5000     0x5000     com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient (3.5.10) <79 10 9 7 5 4 3 1>
108    0 0xffffff7f80eb3000 0xe000     0xe000     com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP (2.2.5) <47 41 5 4 3 1>
112    2 0xffffff7f81530000 0x7000     0x7000     com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib (1.6) <5 4>
113    3 0xffffff7f81537000 0x2f000    0x2f000    com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily (1.8.9fc10) <112 5 4 3 1>
114    1 0xffffff7f81bcb000 0xb7000    0xb7000    com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib (2.3.1f2) <113 112 5 4 3 1>
115    0 0xffffff7f81c8a000 0x7b000    0x7b000    com.apple.driver.AppleHDA (2.3.1f2) <114 113 106 105 82 79 6 5 4 3 1>
117    0 0xffffff7f819f8000 0x3000     0x3000     com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver (122) <33 7 4 3 1>
118    0 0xffffff7f81d42000 0x10000    0x10000    com.apple.driver.AGPM (100.12.69) <87 82 79 10 5 4 3>
120    1 0xffffff7f80807000 0xe000     0xe000     com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily (10.0.6) <7 6 5 4 3 1>
121    0 0xffffff7f80f21000 0xa000     0xa000     com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager (4.0.9f33) <120 7 5 4 3 1>
122    2 0xffffff7f81520000 0x5000     0x5000     com.apple.kext.triggers (1.0) <7 6 5 4 3 1>
123    0 0xffffff7f81525000 0x9000     0x9000     com.apple.filesystems.autofs (3.0) <122 7 6 5 4 3 1>
124    0 0xffffff7f81b41000 0x5000     0x5000     com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor (1.9.5d0) <5 4 3>
125    0 0xffffff7f8156d000 0x5000     0x5000     com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC (1.60) <113 79 10 9 7 5 4 3 1>
126    0 0xffffff7f81e7f000 0x3000     0x3000     com.bresink.driver.BRESINKx86Monitoring (9.0) <5 4 3>
127    3 0xffffff7f81e82000 0x42000    0x42000    org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv (4.2.4) <7 5 4 3 1>
128    0 0xffffff7f81ec4000 0x8000     0x8000     org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB (4.2.4) <127 53 12 7 5 4 3 1>
129    0 0xffffff7f81ecc000 0x5000     0x5000     org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt (4.2.4) <127 7 5 4 3 1>
130    0 0xffffff7f81ed1000 0x6000     0x6000     org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp (4.2.4) <127 5 4 1>
132    0 0xffffff7f81eda000 0x33000    0x33000    com.apple.filesystems.smbfs (1.8) <122 7 6 5 4 3 1>
133    0 0xffffff7f81f0d000 0x2000     0x2000     com.apple.nke.rvi (1.0.0) <7 5 4 3 1>
```

Comment: Does it happen while plugged into an external display?

Comment: no monitor or any external device is involved, except mbp with it's magsafe adapter.

Comment: Try installing and activating Caffeine, and tell me if it still sleeps with that on.

Comment: caffeine or any other such program has no effect.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the SMC?

Comment: I tried almost everything mentioned over the interwebs, but looks like battery connector was loose

Comment: Is it going to sleep, or shutting down and "restarting because of a problem"? Also, update your OSX to 10.8.5 and make sure your firmware is up to date.

Comment: 10.8.6 has known issues on MBPs.  After upgrading to 10.9 (and later on to 10.10) all my issues went away.

Answer (score 1):

I hunted that for a while on my MBA 10.9.2.

To my shame it was the Hot corners  setting :(

[image: hot corner]

So when ever the Mouse was there it obeyed the command.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem and it completely befuddled me for a WHILE. Apps to force it to stay awake, like (I assume) caffeine had no effect. Finally while looking at the logs, I saw that what was happening was not that it was going into sleep but rather that it was going into clamshell mode, meaning it was doing what it was supposed to do when one closes the Macbook. I took it into the Apple store since it was under warranty and told them all of this and sure enough it was a problem with the magnetic sensor in the case that detects whether or not the clamshell is closed. 
They were able to test it quickly without needing to open the case with the use of a magnet that they waved over the case.

I'm sure you could test for it this way yourself but if you don't want to go see Apple (which I actually suggest that you DO because you're going to need a new sensor anyways) you should check the logs to see what's actually happening when it is doing this. It sounds to me very much like this is probably what is going on and if you check the logs you'll know for SURE; if it says it's going into clamshell mode then it's the sensor and it simply needs replaced.

Replacing the sensor solved the problem completely.

If it is not going into clamshell mode then I do not know what to tell you except that at least it didn't hurt to take a look at the log, right?

[MBP Mid 2009 thinks the lid is closed permanently](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14690/mbp-mid-2009-thinks-the-lid-is-closed-permanently) - this is a link to someone who had the same problem; they posted their logs if you wanted to see what the log will say.

Hope this helps.

Comment: check system.log   here's a link on how to view log files http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/3521/os-x-how-to-view-log-files/

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I even installed Caffeine, and it still would go to sleep randomly. Screen "goes black" while I'm using the Macbook Pro early 2009 with OS X 10.8 with present day updates. If I touch the trackpad while the screen is black I hear some noises like the computer is waking up again and it comes back on. Randomly, could be minutes, seconds, or hours it happens again, sometimes several times in a row.

PRAM reset and SMC reset did nothing as well, I even reinstalled OS X and it was doing it during the install, tried the hardware test, everything passed but it was even doing it during the hardware test.

It never happened until I updated to 10.8.

Someone mentioned typing this in the terminal and resetting the computer

```
sudo rm /private/var/vm/sleepimage
```

I'm going to try that and hopefully it works.

Comment: hey, I am also having same issue, does sudo rm /private/var/vm/sleepimage
 worked for you?